# Change members from public to private

Tags: c++, object, dynamic

I have a question about the following code. Its idea is to use the "<<" and ">>" operators to enter and print different values. My question is- how can I make the `anzahl` and `zahlen` members private and not public? If I just type them in privates I can't use them for the methods outside of the class. Is there also something I can modify in the code in order to make it better?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Liste{

public:
int anzahl;
int * zahlen;
Liste (){
cout <<"Objekt List is ready" << endl;
anzahl = 0;
}
~Liste(){
cout <<"Objekt destroyed" << endl;
delete (zahlen);
}
void neue_zahlen(int zahl){

if(zahl == 0){ return;}

if(anzahl == 0){

    zahlen = new int[anzahl+1];
    zahlen[anzahl] = zahl;
    anzahl++;
    }
    else{

    int * neue_zahl = new int[anzahl+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++){
            neue_zahl[i] = zahlen[i];
        }
    neue_zahl[anzahl] = zahl;
    anzahl++;

    delete(zahlen);
    zahlen = neue_zahl;
    }  

    }
    };






 // Liste ausgeben

ostream& operator<<(ostream& Stream, const Liste &list)
{
 cout << '[';
    for(int i=0; i < list.anzahl; i++){

            cout << list.zahlen[i];
    if (i > (list.anzahl-2) {
        cout << ',';
    }
        }
    cout << ']' << endl;

return Stream;
}


//Operator Liste einlesen

istream& operator>>(istream&, tBruch&){

cout<< 

 }




int main(){

Liste liste; //Konstruktor wird aufgerufen
int zahl;
cout <<"enter the numbers" << endl;
do{
      cin >> zahl;
      liste.neue_zahlen(zahl);

    }while(zahl);


  cout<<liste;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Private members can't be accesed by non-member functions. You can make `operator<<` [`friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

```
class Liste{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& Stream, const Liste &list);
    ...
};
```

Or add a member function for it:

```
class Liste{
    public:
    void print(ostream& Stream) const {
        Stream << '[';
        for (int i=0; i < list.anzahl; i++) {
            Stream << list.zahlen[i];
            if (i > (list.anzahl-2) {
                Stream << ',';
            }
        }
        Stream << ']' << endl;
    }
    ...
};
```

then call it from `operator<<`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& Stream, const Liste &list)
{
    list.print(Stream);
    return Stream;
}
```

BTW: You should use `Stream` in `operator<<`, not `cout`.

Comment: Thanks, did it with friend function and it's all working now. I will try it with the other way as well :))